# What do zombie villagers look like in Minecraft Greek Mythology?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to revive a village in Minecraft, and I just recently got the Greek Mythology pack, in which I can't identify zombie villagers (kind of an essential ingredient in repopulating).

Does anyone know what they look like, and more broadly, how do you figure out what various mobs look like in different texture packs?

Comment: What is a "Greek Mythology pack"? And if your question is just how something looks in a specific resource pack, then simply download it and look at it in the game or in the folder.

Comment: @FabianRöling Greek Mythology is [an official "mash-up pack"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/greek-mythology-mash-up/c1kbn0qdctzd?activetab=pivot:overviewtab). The point is that the OP can't distinguish the Zombie Villagers any more since the textures (and models?) got changed.

Comment: Thank you @Joachim that's exactly what I mean. Maybe I'm not familiar enough with Minecraft bedrock edition to know how to preview monsters in a pack, but at night all the zombies seem to look the same, irrespective of whether they are zombies, desert zombies, or zombie villagers

Comment: @e_i_pi you could turn off the texture pack of, find a [Zombie Villager](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Zombie_Villager), and then turn the textures back on and see what it looks like.

Comment: @e_i_pi you could also search it on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com).

Comment: @Joachim So… what is it? Is it a new version of Minecraft that Microsoft invented recently? I don't really keep up with those.

Comment: @FabianRöling Me neither, I just googled it. It's mostly a thematic graphic overhaul. It contains "Greek gods, fantastical creatures and epic locations", " a bespoke texture set and themed UI" and an "orchestral soundtrack".

Comment: Then it needs its own tag, not [tag:minecraft], because it's a separate game. I'll create a meta post to ask around if anyone else knows more about this.

Comment: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13594/171580

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call it a separate game, because it's just skins and textures. That's like changing your clothes and then claiming you're a different person.

Answer (score 8):

Okay, so I've figured it out. In order to find out what various mobs look like, you do the following:

1. Create a new world in Creative Mode
2. Open your inventory
3. Go to the "All" tab
4. Type in "spawn `{monster name}`", and you'll be presented with a spawner of that monster
5. Move the spawner into an inventory slot
6. Close the inventory screen
7. Equip the spawner
8. Right click where you want to spawn the monster

In the Greek Mythology Mash Up, it can be difficult to distinguish between zombie villagers and regular zombies. They both have horns on their heads, suggesting they are modelled off [satyrs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satyr). The main characteristics to look for are:

- Zombie villagers have red and white eyes, zombies are pure red
- Zombie villagers have slightly taller heads
- Zombies wearing clothes are *always* zombie villagers (note, I'm talking clothes, not armour)
- Zombies that are naked are regular zombies if their hair is brown, and zombie villagers if their hair is dark grey and they are wearing a red headband

Below is a screenshot demonstrating the difference between a naked zombie villager (left) and naked regular zombie (right):

[image]

Answer (score -3):

The first zombies you encounter in the Greek Mythology Minecraft pack are Satyr.

Also the spiders are arachne-inspired spiders.